# Can I combine several replications into one p-value using binomial distribution?

Tags: binomial-distribution, multiple-comparisons

Let's say I am interested in whether a certain type of objects "X" possess a certain fancy property. I devised a test for whether each individual object X has this property, and this test produces a p-value for each one object. The test itself is a bit convoluted, but I verified on dummy objects that it detects the effect when it is present, and that for H0 of no effect it produces p below 0.05 in 5% of cases.

Now, I found that in one experimental group (group A, consisting of 14 objects) every single object possesses the quality of interest (each p-value for each object is individually <0.05). In another group however (group B, 16 objects) only 10 out of 16 objects produce p<0.05.

So, I'll address the reasons for "why it happened" separately, by using effect sizes (quantifying this property and comparing it between groups). But I was wondering whether I can use binomial distribution to calculate the overall p-value for the 2nd group to sometimes possess this property, by assuming a binomial distribution with success rate of 0.95, and looking at the cumulative probability of failing to produce enough successes. All experiments are independent from each other, so arguably I could treat p-values as random variables (either coming from same distribution, or different distributions for group A and B). Which would mean that I can treat p<0.05 as independent events (happening with 5% probability at H0 and more than 5% in H1).

For my case, even for group B, it would give me a very low combined p-value: pbinom(16-10,16,0.95) = 6e-10, as I expected to have about 1 p<0.05 in H0, but got 10 instead. Intuitively something is not quite right with this approach, but I cannot quite put a finger on it. Is it wrong? Or am I doing it wrong? Or am I interpreting it wrong? Can I claim in writing that "the effect was present in at least some objects in group B ($p_{binomial}=6\cdot10^{-10}$)", or not?

Or is it a sort of a case when the answer is "you can, but it's stupid; do THIS OTHER THING instead"?

I don't know if I'm missing something obvious. I'm aware of Fisher method of combining p-values, although I haven't ever used it in practice.

Answer (score 2):

If you want some sense of an overall p-value you could combine them in this way (given suitable assumptions), though it seems to throw away a lot of information.

Consider, for example, if you had 14 independent tests that all had p-values below $\frac12$ (rather than $0.05$). This would be strong evidence against the null!

Fisher's method would easily see that, yours would probably not unless there were a considerable increase in the proportion below 0.05.

Comment: Good point, thank you! I'm also gradually leaning towards recalculating everything properly, with a Fisher method.

Comment: If the thing you're looking at does what you want it to, there's no real problem; it depends on what you need to achieve. Fisher's method is the most obvious overall method -- it's the most natural one in a particular sense, and a good choice for a number of reasons, but not the only one.